# How to properly clear a list from unique matches in file reading -> file writing

Tags: python, list, file-io

I have a series of files for which I am extracting strings, using the re.search() function.

The file I am writing to is a tab delimited list that includes names, hsa and matSEQID and matACC. Both matSEQID and matACC are to be a commadelimited list, which I am creating using the ','.join() function.

I am struggling with how to properly write to the new file with the first row including only the values pulled from the first file. Currently, the names and hsa columns are correct, but the other two columns is either every single match from all the files, or only the matches from the last file, depending on how I clear the list. How do I make the row unique? I am trying to clear the list after every file but that does not seem to be working properly. Am I thinking about this correctly? Thank you

```
import re
import os
import sys

List_of_names = []
List_of_hsa = []
List_of_matSEQID = []
List_of_matACC = []
fileList = []

path = "/blah/blah/blah/stuff/"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

for file in dirs:
    fileList.append(path+file)

outname = sys.argv[1]

output_fhandle = open(outname, "w")


def linesplitter(M_object):
    Temp_storage = M_object.group()
    new_storage1 = Temp_storage.split(">")
    new_storage2 = new_storage1[1].split("<")
    List_of_names.append(new_storage2[0])

def stem_patternID(M_object):
    string = M_object.group()
    List_of_hsa.append(string)

def mat_seqID(M_object):
    string = M_object.group()
    List_of_matSEQID.append(string)

for file in fileList:
    fh_html = open(file).readlines()
    for line in fh_html:
        temp_string = line
        match_object = re.search(acc_pattern, temp_string)
        match_obj2 = re.search(stem_pattern, temp_string)
        match_obj3 = re.search(mature_seq_pattern, temp_string)
        match_obj4 = re.search(mature_acc_pattern, temp_string)
        if (match_object):
            linesplitter(match_object)
        if(match_obj2):
            stem_patternID(match_obj2)
        if(match_obj3):
            mat_seqID(match_obj3)
        if(match_obj4):
            mature_acc_func(match_obj4)

        my_matseqid_string = ','.join(List_of_matSEQID)
        mat_acc_string = ','.join(List_of_matACC)

        with open(outname,"w") as f:
                for (name,hsa) in zip(List_of_names, List_of_hsa):
                        f.write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\n".format(name,hsa,my_matseqid_string,mat_acc_string))
        List_of_matSEQID.clear()
        List_of_matACC.clear()
```

If I remove the .clear() function at the end, then every single match is contained within that list. If I keep it then I only get the matches made from the last file. How do I make it so that it is printing to file in column 2 and 3 the list with the values from that are unique for that given file?
Thank you

Here are the two INCORRECT output files:
1) With .clear() left as is.

```
MI0023620       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7159 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023613       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7153 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023562       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-6077-2       Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023619       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7161 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023616       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7156 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023612       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7152 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023565       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-6511a-3      Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023622       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-486-2        Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023431       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-6511b-2      Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023611       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7151 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023618       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7158 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023563       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-6089-2       Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023564       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-6511a-2      Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023561       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-3690-2       Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023623       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7162 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023610       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7150 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023614       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7154 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023615       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7155 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023617       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7157 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023566       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-6511a-4      Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023621       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7160 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
```

2) top 3 rows with .clear() removed

```
MI0023620       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7159 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7159-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7159-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7153-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7153-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6077,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7161-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7161-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7156-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7156-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7152-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7152-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-486-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-486-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511b-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511b-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7151-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7151-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7158-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7158-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6089,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-3690,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7162-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7162-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7150,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7154-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7154-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7155-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7155-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7157-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7157-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p       MIMAT0028228,MIMAT0028229,MIMAT0028216,MIMAT0028217,MIMAT0023702,MIMAT0028232,MIMAT0028233,MIMAT0028222,MIMAT0028223,MIMAT0028214,MIMAT0028215,MIMAT0025478,MIMAT0025479,MIMAT0002177,MIMAT0004762,MIMAT0025847,MIMAT0025848,MIMAT0028212,MIMAT0028213,MIMAT0028226,MIMAT0028227,MIMAT0023714,MIMAT0025478,MIMAT0025479,MIMAT0018119,MIMAT0028234,MIMAT0028235,MIMAT0028211,MIMAT0028218,MIMAT0028219,MIMAT0028220,MIMAT0028221,MIMAT0028224,MIMAT0028225,MIMAT0025478,MIMAT0025479,MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023613       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-7153 Mature sequence hsa-miR-7159-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7159-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7153-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7153-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6077,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7161-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7161-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7156-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7156-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7152-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7152-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-486-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-486-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511b-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511b-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7151-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7151-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7158-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7158-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6089,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-3690,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7162-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7162-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7150,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7154-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7154-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7155-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7155-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7157-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7157-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p       MIMAT0028228,MIMAT0028229,MIMAT0028216,MIMAT0028217,MIMAT0023702,MIMAT0028232,MIMAT0028233,MIMAT0028222,MIMAT0028223,MIMAT0028214,MIMAT0028215,MIMAT0025478,MIMAT0025479,MIMAT0002177,MIMAT0004762,MIMAT0025847,MIMAT0025848,MIMAT0028212,MIMAT0028213,MIMAT0028226,MIMAT0028227,MIMAT0023714,MIMAT0025478,MIMAT0025479,MIMAT0018119,MIMAT0028234,MIMAT0028235,MIMAT0028211,MIMAT0028218,MIMAT0028219,MIMAT0028220,MIMAT0028221,MIMAT0028224,MIMAT0028225,MIMAT0025478,MIMAT0025479,MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
MI0023562       Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-6077-2       Mature sequence hsa-miR-7159-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7159-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7153-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7153-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6077,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7161-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7161-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7156-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7156-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7152-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7152-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-486-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-486-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511b-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511b-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7151-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7151-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7158-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7158-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6089,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-3690,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7162-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7162-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7150,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7154-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7154-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7155-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7155-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7157-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7157-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-6511a-3p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p,Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p       MIMAT0028228,MIMAT0028229,MIMAT0028216,MIMAT0028217,MIMAT0023702,MIMAT0028232,MIMAT0028233,MIMAT0028222,MIMAT0028223,MIMAT0028214,MIMAT0028215,MIMAT0025478,MIMAT0025479,MIMAT0002177,MIMAT0004762,MIMAT0025847,MIMAT0025848,MIMAT0028212,MIMAT0028213,MIMAT0028226,MIMAT0028227,MIMAT0023714,MIMAT0025478,MIMAT0025479,MIMAT0018119,MIMAT0028234,MIMAT0028235,MIMAT0028211,MIMAT0028218,MIMAT0028219,MIMAT0028220,MIMAT0028221,MIMAT0028224,MIMAT0028225,MIMAT0025478,MIMAT0025479,MIMAT0028230,MIMAT0028231
```

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% understand - is it correct to say the issue with 1) is that both the first and second lines contain `Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-5p` and `Mature sequence hsa-miR-7160-3p` but you only want them to contain the unique values (only the first)?

Comment: like @DominicD, I'm not sure I follow. What's the correct expected output? It would be great if you could provide sample input and expected output in the question.

Comment: Row 1 col0 and row1 col1 are both unique for that file that's read in. So the length of the output is dependent on the number of files. But sometimes I have two or three matches from the re.search() function, and I am trying to store that in a list, but convert the list to a delimitted comma string.                                                               The correct expected output would be col2 and col3 containing unique values for that given file. So I believe I'm not storing the values correctly in the process of copying them from the read in file but I'm not sure how

Comment: what about col2 and col3? Do you want them to contain the entire history (from multiple files?)

Comment: I want col2 and col3 to contain unique values for that file.

Comment: @SamGrow - it would really be best if you could include some input (like two input files that lead to bad results), and the expected output you'd like to get. That way, one can understand the question better. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example